# Calling Shell Script with JavaScript for Automation

Tags: javascript, applescript, javascript-automation

Using AppleScript I can call a shell script with:

```
do shell script "echo 'Foo & Bar'"
```

But I can't find a way to do this with JavaScript in the Yosemite Script Editor.

Comment: Maybe this helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586694/pipe-to-subprocess-stdin-for-jxa

Comment: I'd recommend looking into Cocoa's `NSTask` as it's much more robust and capable than `do shell script`.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201173/how-to-call-a-shell-command-from-javascript-jxa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`do shell script` is part of the Standard Scripting Additions, so something like this should work:

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true
app.doShellScript("echo 'Foo & Bar'")
```

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* [ShooTerKo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048221/45375):

When calling the shell, **properly quoting arguments embedded in the command is important**:

To that end, AppleScript provides `quoted form of` for safely using variable values as arguments in a shell command, without fear of having the values altered by the shell or breaking the command altogether.

Curiously, as of OSX 10.11, **there appears to be no JXA equivalent of `quoted form of`, but, it's easy to implement one's own** (credit goes to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28773207/45375#comment-45841642) on another answer and [calum_b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476909/calum-b)'s later correction):

```js
// This is the JS equivalent of AppleScript's `quoted form of`
function quotedForm(s) { return "'" + s.replace(/'/g, "'\\''") + "'" }
```

From what I can tell, this does exactly what AppleScript's `quoted form of` does.

<sup>It encloses the argument in single-quotes, which protects it from shell expansions; since single-quoted shell strings don't support escaping *embedded* single-quotes, an input string with single-quotes is broken into multiple, single-quoted substrings, with the embedded single-quotes spliced in via `\'`, which the shell then reassembles into a single literal.</sup>

**Example:**

```js
var app = Application.currentApplication(); app.includeStandardAdditions = true

function quotedForm(s) { return "'" + s.replace(/'/g, "'\\''") + "'" }

// Construct value with spaces, a single quote, and other shell metacharacters
// (those that must be quoted to be taken literally).
var arg = "I'm a value that needs quoting - |&;()<>"

// This should echo arg unmodified, thanks to quotedForm();
// It is the equivalent of AppleScript `do shell script "echo " & quoted form of arg`:
console.log(app.doShellScript("echo " + quotedForm(arg)))
```

---

Alternatively, **if your JXA script happens to load a custom AppleScript library anyway**, [BallpointBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5496433/ballpointben) suggests 
doing the following (lightly edited):

> If you have an AppleScript library you reference in JS using `var lib = Library("lib")`, you may wish to add
>
> ```js
> on quotedFormOf(s)
>   return quoted form of s
> end quotedFormOf
> ```
>
> to this library.
>   This will make the AppleScript implementation of quoted form  of available everywhere, as `lib.quotedFormOf(s)`

Comment: Thanks, @BallpointBen - I've added your suggestion to the bottom of the answer, with some minor additions.