# How to call a shell command from JavaScript JXA?

Tags: applescript, osascript, javascript-automation

I have an AppleScript script that is calling a shell command that I want to convert to JavaScript (JXA) but I don't see the equivalent of `do shell script`.

Here is the script using AppleScript:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv

    set convertScript to "export -i '" & first item of argv  & "' -o '" & second item of argv & ".csv'"

    do shell script convertScript

end run
```

My desktop application calls this script and then the script executes the shell command.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044758/calling-shell-script-with-javascript-for-automation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using the following command:

```
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
return app.doShellScript('ls');
```

From [here](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/jxa-execute-shell-script-and-get-results/5955).