# How to get POSIX path of the current script's folder in JavaScript for Automation?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite, osascript, javascript-automation

In AppleScript it’s possible to get the the POSIX path of the folder the current script is located in using this line:

```
POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
```

Example result: `/Users/aaron/Git/test/`

What’s the JavaScript equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way *[NOTE: I NO LONGER RECOMMEND THIS METHOD. SEE EDIT, BELOW]*:

```
app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
path = app.pathTo(this);
app.doShellScript('dirname \'' + path + '\'') + '/';
```

note the single quotes surrounding `path` to work with paths with spaces, etc., in the doShellScript

**EDIT** 
After being slapped on the hand by @foo for using a fairly unsafe path-quoting method, I'd like to amend this answer with:

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa");
app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
thePath = app.pathTo(this);

thePathStr = $.NSString.alloc.init;
thePathStr = $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String(thePath);
thePathStrDir = (thePathStr.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent);

thePathStrDir.js + "/";
```

If you're going to use this string, of course, you still have to deal with whether or not it has questionable characters in it. But at least at this stage this is not an issue. This also demonstrates a few concepts available to the JXA user, like using the ObjC bridge and `.js` to get the string "coerced" to a JavaScript string (from NSString).

Comment: Nice! I wasn’t aware of `this`.

Comment: "note the single quotes surrounding path to work with paths with spaces" ...which completely blows up if the path string contains single quotes instead. _Never_ generate code without _fully_ sanitizing your inputs: it's totally unsafe. When working with `do shell script`, always use `function quotedForm(s) {return "'"+s.replace("'","'\\''")+"'"}` to correctly single-quote your arbitrary text before concatenating it, e.g. `app.doShellScript('dirname ' + quotedForm(path))`.

Comment: thank you, @foo - I've changed (added to) my answer.

Comment: @CRGreen Thanks for the edit! Great that we got rid of the shell call. I’ve created slightly changed version of your code—please see my answer below.

Comment: @foo: great tip, but it should be `function quotedForm(s) { return "'" + s.replace(/'/g, "'\\''") + "'" }`, to ensure that _all_ embedded `'` instances are "escaped".

Comment: @mklement0 Amazing that the first comment correcting this mistake came nearly two years later... two seconds of testing would have caught this mistake.

Comment: Looks like all I needed is app.pathTo(this) from all that. Thanks!

Comment: `app.pathTo(this)` points to the Script Editor app, not the script itself.

Answer (score 9):

Pure JXA code without ObjC involved:

```
App = Application.currentApplication()
App.includeStandardAdditions = true
SystemEvents = Application('System Events')

var pathToMe = App.pathTo(this)
var containerPOSIXPath = SystemEvents.files[pathToMe.toString()].container().posixPath()
```

Comment: Kudos for figuring out a pure JXA method. A side benefit is that `SystemEvents.files[pathToMe.toString()].container()` gives you access to a full-fledged object with properties reporting information about the folder. A potential down-side - which probably won't matter much for a single call - is that this method is much slower than using the ObjC bridge via `$(App.pathTo(this).toString()).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent.js` (based on my informal tests, around 5-6 times slower).

Answer (score 4):

To complement the helpful existing answers by providing **self-contained utility functions**:

```js
// Return the POSIX path of the folder hosting this script / app.
// E.g., from within '/foo/bar.scpt', returns '/foo'.
function myPath() {
    var app = Application.currentApplication(); app.includeStandardAdditions = true
    return $(app.pathTo(this).toString()).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent.js
}

// Return the filename root (filename w/o extension) of this script / app.
// E.g., from within '/foo/bar.scpt', returns 'bar'.
// (Remove `.stringByDeletingPathExtension` if you want to retain the extension.)
function myName() {
    var app = Application.currentApplication(); app.includeStandardAdditions = true
    return $(app.pathTo(this).toString()).lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension.js
}
```

Note: These functions make use of the **shortcut syntax forms for the ObjC bridge** (`$(...)` for `ObjC.wrap()` and `.js` for `ObjC.unwrap()`, and also take advantage of the fact that the `Foundation` framework's symbols are available *by default* - see the [OS X 10.10 JXA release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1).

---

It's easy to generalize these functions to provide the **equivalents of the POSIX `dirname` and `basename` utilities**:

```js
// Returns the parent path of the specified filesystem path.
// A trailing '/' in the input path is ignored.
// Equivalent of the POSIX dirname utility.
// Examples:
//    dirname('/foo/bar') // -> '/foo'
//    dirname('/foo/bar/') // ditto
function dirname(path) {
  return $(path.toString()).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent.js
}

// Returns the filename component of the specified filesystem path.
// A trailing '/' in the input path is ignored.
// If the optional <extToStrip> is specified:
//   - If it it is a string, it is removed from the result, if it matches at
//     the end (case-sensitively) - do include the '.'
//   - Otherwise (Boolean or number), any truthy value causes any extension
//     (suffix) present to be removed.
// Equivalent of the POSIX basename utility; the truthy semantics of the
// 2nd argument are an extension.
// Examples:
//    basename('/foo/bar') // -> 'bar'
//    basename('/foo/bar/') // ditto
//    basename('/foo/bar.scpt', 1) // -> 'bar'
//    basename('/foo/bar.scpt', '.scpt') // -> 'bar'
//    basename('/foo/bar.jxa', '.scpt') // -> 'bar.jxa'
function basename(path, extToStrip) {
  path = path.toString()
  if (path[path.length-1] === '/') { path = path.slice(0, -1) }
  if (typeof extToStrip === 'string') {
    return path.slice(-extToStrip.length) === extToStrip ? $(path).lastPathComponent.js.slice(0, -extToStrip.length) : $(path).lastPathComponent.js    
  } else { // assumed to be numeric: if truthy, strip any extension
    return extToStrip ? $(path).lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension.js : $(path).lastPathComponent.js    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So to sum up what I’m doing now, I’m answering my own question. Using @foo’s and @CRGreen’s excellent responses, I came up with the following:

```js
ObjC.import('Foundation');
var app, path, dir;

app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

path = app.pathTo(this);
dir = $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String(path).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent.js + '/';
```

This is quite close to @CRGreen’s response, however, it’s a bit more terse and I’m importing `Foundation` instead of `Cocoa`. Plus, I’m declaring the variables I’m using to avoid accidental globals.

Comment: I've read up a bit about the advantages of using Foundation, but perhaps you can chime in here as to your reasons for using it, @aaronk6

Comment: @CRGreen I’m no Mac or iOS developer but my naïve assumption was that `Foundation` is probably smaller than `Cocoa` which consists of `Foundation Kit`, `Application Kit`, `Core Data`, and others.

Comment: Nicely done; @CRGreen: To quote from the [OSX 10.10 JXA release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1): "The symbols from the Foundation framework are available by default in JavaScript for Automation". In other words: no need for an explicit `Objc.import('Foundation')`. Also, using the shortcut syntax for wrapping JS objects, we can simplify to `dir = $(path).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent.js + '/'`

Answer (score 2):

Use `-[NSString stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]`, which already knows how to remove the last path segment safely:

```
ObjC.import('Foundation')

path = ObjC.unwrap($(path).stringByDeletingLastPathComponent)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer the more dangerous life, you could use a regular expression to strip the last path segment from a POSIX path string. Off the top of my head (caveat emptor, etc):

```
path = path.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/*$/,'').replace(/^$/,'/')
```

(Note that the second `replace()` is required to process paths with <2 parts correctly.)

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a simpler way to get the parent folder without invoking ObjC.

```js
var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
thePath = app.pathTo(this);

Path(thePath + '/../../')
```

Comment: Nice, but to get the folder in which the script is located you just need `Path(thePath + '/..')` (only _one_ level up).

Comment: Actually, normalization of the path (resolution of the `/..`) only _appears_ to happen and seems to be an artifact of the implicit result printed by Script Editor; e.g., for script `/foo/dir/script`, letting Script Editor print the result of `Path(thePath + '/..')` implicitly shows `/foo/dir`, but if you inspect the value with `console.log` or perform string concatenation, you'll get `/foo/dir/script/..`, i.e., the non-normalized path.

Answer (score -2):

Lots of interesting solutions above.

Here's mine, which does NOT require ObjC, and returns an object with properties likely to be needed.

```
'use strict';
var oScript = getScriptProp(this);

/*oScript Properties
    Path
    Name
    ParentPath
    Folder
*/

oScript.ParentPath;

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

function getScriptProp(pRefObject) {

  var app = Application.currentApplication()
  app.includeStandardAdditions = true

  var pathScript = app.pathTo(pRefObject).toString();
  var pathArr = pathScript.split("/")

  var oScript = {
    Path: pathScript,
    Name: pathArr[pathArr.length - 1],
    ParentPath: pathArr.slice(0, pathArr.length - 1).join("/"),
    Folder: pathArr[pathArr.length - 2]
  };

  return oScript
}
```

Comment: `app.pathTo(this)` points to the Script Editor app, not the script bundle itself.